# Are there any $3$-Fermat-pseudoprimes of the form $k^4+1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, pseudoprimes

Suppose $k$ is a positive integer and $N:=k^4+1$ is composite.

> Can $N$ be a $3$-Fermat-pseudoprime; that is, can the congruence $$3^{N-1}\equiv 1 \mod{N}$$ hold ?

I checked up to $k=10^8$ and found no example. Is this simple test in fact sufficient for numbers of the form $k^4+1$ ?

Comment: Interesting.. if I'm reading correctly, $3^{N-1}\equiv 1 \mod N \Rightarrow N$ is prime

Comment: @ganeshie8 In fact, I hope this is the case for those numbers.

Comment: I extended the search limit to $3\cdot 10^8$, assuming we can trust the ispseudoprime-command for the numbers $N$ in this range.

Comment: @Peter I've added [examples-counterexamples] tag to few of your questions, feel free to attach it elsewhere you find suitable.

Comment: Search range extended to $k=2\cdot 10^9$

Comment: @AgentS this is not what Fermat's Little Theorem means. It means if $N$ is a prime, then $3^{N-1} \equiv 1 \mod N$ and not necessarily the other way round. See http://oeis.org/A005935 for examples of composite numbers that satisfy the relation (couldn't find $k^4+1$ forms).

Comment: @DS This comment refers to the form of the number in the question : $N=k^4+1$ with positive integer $k$

Comment: @Peter The comment makes a common misconception that $a^{N-1} \equiv 1 \mod N \implies N$ is a prime. Just pointing out that.

Comment: Due to some congruences we get restrictions on $k$, e.g. take 10, we have that $3^{10m-1} \bmod {10m}$ will always have a 3 or a 7 as ending digit and the congruence can thus never hold if $10\mid N$, for 34 this means that $k \bmod 34$ cannot be in $\{9,15,19,25\}$, 82 gives $k \bmod 82 \notin \{3,27,55,79\}$, $k \bmod 146 \notin \{51,63,83,95\}$, $k \bmod 386 \notin \{9,43,343,377\}$, and similar congruences cannot hold with 1681 and 94177 as modulo (and possibly others). This sadly only reduces the amount of $k$ to check by a little less than 20%. For $N=k^3+1$ this is over 68%.

Comment: In fact, 178, 194, 226, 274, 289, ... are other such numbers, this way 33% of all $k$'s can be left unchecked (note that it also takes time to do these modulo operations, thus too many would slow down the algorithm).

Comment: Checked all $k < 2 \cdot 10^{11}$.

Comment: @jorisperrenet A huge search limit. Apparently , my computer is too old for such calculations. I needed already quite long for the humble $2\cdot 10^9$. Anyway, thanks.